# Calculating maximum int value in C program (1 << 31) - 1

Tags: c

Compiling this with gcc (4.6.3) yields no warnings and produces -2147483648 as the result.

```
printf ("%d", (1<<31));
```

Compiling this yields "warning: integer overflow in expression [-Woverflow]" and produces 2147483647 as the result.

```
printf ("%d". (1<<31)-1);
```

I am confused why the second expression gives the integer overflow warning.

Comment: (1<<31)-1 needs 32 bits to represent so its a overflow.

Comment: You can also negate the bits in order to avoid this: `~(1 << 31)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although `1<<31` is arguably undefined behaviour for a signed 32 bit integer, it typically results in the maximum negative 32 bit 2's complement integer value (`0x80000000 = -2147483648`). If you try to subtract 1 from this value then the value *underflows* and becomes the maximum positive value, hence the compiler warning.

```
 1<<31      0x80000000                -2147483648
(1<<31)-1   0x80000000-1 = 0x7fffffff  2147483647
```

Comment: I wouldn't say that that's what 1<<31 is, it's really undefined/implementation-defined behaviour...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth isn't `1<<32` a UB condition?(assuming int is 32 bits).

Comment: @Koushik: yes, but so is 1<<31. It represents a value outside the range of a 32-bit signed integer.

Comment: Also, to continue my pedantry, this isn't underflow. AFAIK, underflow refers to numbers that quantise to zero in floating-point.

Comment: @Oli: the term *underflow* apparently has multiple meanings but it is commonly used to describe an overflow between positive and negative integers, see e.g. http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/191.html

Answer (score 2):

The `%d` prints an integer. When you do `(1<<31)` you are creating an integer `-2147483648`, which is the lowest 32 bit number. So when you try `(1<<31) - 1` you are trying to represent a negative number which can not be represented by 32 bits! so it underflow and giving you `2147483647`  (wrap around).

Answer (score -1):

```
define MAXVAL ((long int) ((unsigned long) (1 << 31) - 1))
```

This construct gets rid of the compiler warnings. Just make the types whatever you need to handle the math and results. This one uses an `unsigned long` to hold the math and then converts the result to the desired type of `long int`.

Now compiling:

```
 long int x = MAXVAL;
```

This will not produce the **overflow warning**.