# Bit shift with a signed int resets one bit too much

Tags: c, bit-shift, unsigned

Please have a look at the following code snippet, which basically simply bit shifts 1 byte by 24 bits to the left.

```
uint64_t i = 0xFFFFFFFF00000000;
printf("before: %016llX \n", i);
i += 0xFF << 24;
printf("after : %016llX \n", i);

// gives:
// before: FFFFFFFF00000000
// after : FFFFFFFEFF000000
```

The most significant 32 bits are `FFFFFFFE` (watch the `E` at the end). This is not as I expected. I don't see why shifting 1 bytes 24 bits left would touch bit #32 (bit #31 should be the last one modified) It changed the last `F` (`1111`) into `E` (`1110`)).

To make it work properly, I had use `0xFF` unsigned (`0xFFU`).

```
uint64_t i = 0xFFFFFFFF00000000;
printf("before: %016llX \n", i);
i += 0xFFU << 24;
printf("after : %016llX \n", i);

// gives:
// before: FFFFFFFF00000000
// after : FFFFFFFFFF000000
```

Why does the bit shift with a signed int (`0xFF`) touch/reset one bit too much?

Comment: But you aren't simply shifting. You are also doing addition.

Comment: I think `0xFF` forces the compiler to cast your value to `int64_t`. Am I wrong? https://godbolt.org/z/88T16Y5G5

Comment: @Hrant no, there's no cast in `0xFF << 24`. The entire shift was done in `int` precision, **then** the result is cast to `uint64_t` [Why does shifting 0xff left by 24 bits result in an incorrect value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46246411/995714), [bit shifting with unsigned long type produces wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31744305/995714)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You left-shifted into the sign bit.

The integer constant `0xFF` has type `int`.  Assuming an `int` is 32 bit, the expression `0xFF << 24` shifts a bit set to 1 into the high-order bit of a signed integer triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which in your case manifested as an unexpected value.

This is spelled out in section 6.5.7p4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The  result  of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit  positions;  vacated  bits  are  filled  with zeros.  If `E1` has  an  unsigned  type,  the  value  of  the  result  is E1×2<sup>E2</sup>, reduced  modulo one  more  than  the  maximum  value  representable  in  the  result  type.  If `E1` has  a  signed type  and  nonnegative  value,  and E1×2<sup>E2</sup>is  representable  in  the  result  type,  then  that  is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

By using the `U` suffix this makes the constant have type `unsigned int`, and it is valid to shift bits set to 1 into the high-order bit because there is no sign bit.

Comment: I think it is implementation defined behavior?

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's undefined as per 6.5.7p4.  Right shifting a negative value is implementation defined.

Comment: Ah, my bad. I used to trust my memory once :)

Comment: @dbush Uah ... perfect answer. That explains it all. Many thanks!

Comment: @dbush Assuming ```0xFF``` would be an ```unsigned char``` instead of ```unsigned int```, would 6.5.7p4 also apply? So replace ```0xFF``` above by ```c``` defined as ```unsigned char c = 0xFF```. This doesn't work, despite it's unsigned.

Comment: @geohei That's because the `unsigned char` value is first *promoted* to type `int` before being used in a expression.